# Start memory profiling of .NET Core app using dotMemory command line profiler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, memory-profiling, dotmemory

I am trying to do some memory profiling of an ASP.NET Core web application using the dotMemory command line profiler on a Debian 64-bit VM. I am able to run the app (with process id 1234 for example) and then attach the memory profiler following instructions given on the [JetBrains help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotmemory/Working_with_dotMemory_Command-Line_Profiler.html).

```
./dotMemory.sh attach 1234 --save-to-dir=~/Snapshots
```

I now want to start the app using the memory profiler to get more information. This is not working however.

- I get the following error when I try to run the profiler as described on the help page.

  `/PathToScript/dotMemory.sh start /PathToWebApp/bin/WebApp --save-to-dir=~/Snapshots`

> A fatal error occurred. The required library libhostfxr.so could not
> be found.
>
> If this is a self-contained application, that library should
> exist in [/PathToWebApp/bin/].
>
> If this is a framework-dependent
> application, install the runtime in the global location
> [/usr/share/dotnet] or use the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable to
> specify the runtime location or register the runtime location in
> [/etc/dotnet/install_location].
>
> The .NET runtime can be found at:
>
> - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=debian.9-x64&apphost_version=5.0.8

- I get a different error when I try to run the profiler with the ".dll" as part of the app name.

  `/PathToScript/dotMemory.sh start /PathToWebApp/bin/WebApp.dll --save-to-dir=~/Snapshots`

> Unable to start profiling. An error occurred trying to start process '/PathToWebApp/bin/WebApp.dll' with working directory '/PathToWebApp'. Exec format error

- I also tried using the `dotnet` keyword.

  `/PathToScript/dotMemory.sh start dotnet /PathToWebApp/bin/WebApp.dll --save-to-dir=~/Snapshots`

> Value of argument  is invalid. File doesn't exist: dotnet

Note that I am able to start the WebApp successfully using the same command.

```
 dotnet /PathToWebApp/bin/WebApp.dll
```

How can I launch the application using the dotMemory profiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the [answer from JetBrains support](https://dotnettools-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/7560694419218-Start-memory-profiling-of-NET-Core-app-using-dotMemory-command-line-profiler): need to use the `start-net-core` command to start an application using the dll.

```
/PathToScript/dotMemory.sh start-net-core /PathToWebApp/bin/WebApp.dll --save-to-dir=~/Snapshots
```